# Installation on Mac OS is not working, JDK 8 Update cant be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: macos, java-8

Go to finder locate the installation dmg file, right click and open. You will be prompted with the next steps as usual.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue.
Oracle has documented the solution.
Here is the link:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/using-jdk-jre-macos-catalina-5781620.html